# What kind of bin packing problem is this?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, integer-programming

I have a problem formulation but it does not resemble the usual packing problem I find in the literature but it is a usual problem in the packing industry. I just do not know the name for it.

The problem formulation is as follows: Ich have a certain amount of objects with different weights (around 10000) and I want to pack them in boxes. The objective is that all boxes should have the same weight (at least within a predefined boundary). It is not mandatory that all objects are distributed.

How can I formulate this optimization problem and what algorithms may suitable to solve this problem?
Is there a name for this problem in the literature?

Comment: It seems to be a relaxation of what is called an "equal sums" problem, as you are trying to get subsets whose weights have nearly equal sums.  For example one might divide the items into two groups whose weights are as close to half the total as possible.

Comment: See [multiway number partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning) problem.